# Xamarin.Forms: Creating a SearchBar and search on a ListView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day everyone. I'm currently doing an application that allows the User to CRUD record of an Customer and save it on a database.
All the created records are displayed on a ListView.

What I want to do is to create a SearchBar that allows me to search Customer Records that is inside my ListView. In a separate program, I've tried to create a searchbar but I was only able to search records from a pre-defined ListView.

The searchbar I need to do should allow me to search on a ListView that comes from a database.

Hope you can help me with this.

Here are some of my codes. If you need to see more. Please let me know. Thanks a lot.

**CustomerViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Services;

    namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels
    {
    public class CustomerVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private List<Customer> _customerList;


    public List<Customer> CustomerList
    {
        get { return _customerList; }
        set
        {
            _customerList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }




    public CustomerVM()
    {
        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var customerServices = new CustomerServices();

        CustomerList = await customerServices.GetCustomerAsync();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


    }
}
```

**CustomerPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.ClientListPage"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
         BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
         Title="Client List">


  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:CustomerVM/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>


  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">



    <ListView x:Name="CustomerListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

              <controls:CircleImage Source="icon.png"
                 HeightRequest="66"
                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 Aspect="AspectFill"
                 WidthRequest="66"
                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
               />


              <Label Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_NAME}"
                 TextColor="#24e97d"
                 FontSize="24"/>



          <Label Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_CODE}"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="18"
                   Opacity="0.6"/>


          <Label Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_CONTACT}"
               TextColor="White"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>



        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>


<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
         Padding="30,10,30,10"
         HeightRequest="20"
         BackgroundColor="#24e97d"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         Opacity="0.5">
  <Label Text="© Copyright 2016   SMESOFT.COM.PH   All Rights Reserved "
         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>



</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Try to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy where should I put that? Will it solve my problem Sir?

Comment: `public List<Customer> CustomerList` to `public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList`. Also I don't see `SearchBar` and search logic.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy it does not solved my problem Sir. Because my focus actually is on how am I going to search records from a ListView. Records that comes from a database and are not pre-defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SearchBar` has `SearchCommand` property. Bind it to some your `ICommand` on view model. Also bind `Text` property of `SearchBar` to `string` property on view model. Keep all records in some common collection `_allCustomers` and on UI show only `ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers`. In execution method for this command you could add:

```
private void SearchCommandExecute()
{
    var tempRecords = _allCustomers.Where(c=>c.FullName.Contains(Text));
    Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(tempRecords);
}
```

Comment: How can I bind the Text property of a searchbar to string in viewmodel?

Comment: `<SearchBar Text={Binding TextOnViewModelPropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}>`

Comment: I have this code in XAML  :  <SearchBar Placeholder="Search"
               SearchCommand="ICommand"
               Text="{Binding CustomerList, Mode=TwoWay}"/>                                              Am I doing the right thing? How will I use the ICommand code in SearchCommand? I do not use an observable collection because it's not functioning well. This is my current code in viewmodel: http://pastie.org/10906667

Comment: You should bind `Text` of `SearchBar` to `string` property on view model not to `List`. `ICommand` is a type. So better way is to bind `SearchCommand` of `SearchBar` to property of type `ICommand` on view model. What is wrong with `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: I would suggest you to investigate articles related to Xamarin.Forms development, [for example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117291/discussion-between-jaycee-evangelista-and-egor-gromadskiy).

Comment: I'll read that Sir thanks. What code should I put inside the Text binding in my view model Sir?

Comment: Sir. Is this how to assign the Text and ICommand Property?  <SearchBar Placeholder="Search"
               Text="{Binding TextOnViewModelPropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}"
               SearchCommand="ICommand"/>                                                         I declare it in view model like this : http://pastie.org/10906925

Comment: `<SearchBar Placeholder="Search" Text="{Binding TextOnViewModelPropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>`

Comment: How about this code:                                                  public string TextOnViewModelPropertyName { get; set; }
public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }   ? What should I put inside it?

Comment: You should initialize `public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }`

Comment: These are the codes I have changed. CustomerListPage - http://pastie.org/10907735  CustomerViewModel - http://pastie.org/10907732   CustomerServices - http://pastie.org/10907737   RestClient.cs - http://pastie.org/10907739  Can you please take a look at this? Am I doing right? What do I need to add Sir? Thanks a lot Man for helping me. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Make your `TextOnViewModelPropertyName` property notifiable too, like your `CustomerList`(use `OnPropertyChanged()` in setter). Also you should initialize your `SearchCommand` in constructor of view model (`SearchCommand = new Command (() => Debug.WriteLine ("Command executed"));`)

Comment: should I do TextOnViewModelPropertyName like this?         public string TextOnViewModelPropertyName
        {
            get
            {
                return _customerList;
            }
            set
            {
                _customerList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: `private string _searchedText;
public string SearchedText 
{ 
    get { return _searchedText; }
    set 
    {  
        _searchedText = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}`

Comment: Oh. How about the SearchCommand? Is this correct?  private void SearchCommandExecute()
        {
            var tempRecords = _customerList.Where(c => c.FullName.Contains(Text));
            Customer = new List<Customer>(tempRecords);
        }
        public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }

Comment: Kind of, but from your comment I see, that `SearchCommand` doesn't know anything about `SearchCommandExecute`

Comment: yes Sir it doesn't know. What should I add or remove?

Comment: _Also you should initialize your SearchCommand in constructor of view model (`SearchCommand = new Command (() => Debug.WriteLine ("Command executed"));`)_

Comment: Like this? 
        public CustomerVM()
        {
            InitializeDataAsync();
        }

        private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
        {
            var customerServices = new CustomerServices();

            CustomerList = await customerServices.GetCustomerAsync();
            SearchCommand = new Command(() => Debug.WriteLine("Command executed"));
        }

Comment: Yeap, kind of. But instead of `Debug.WriteLine("Command executed")` put your code for searching.

Comment: but I don't have code yet for searching? :( Please tell me what to code. Can you check my codes Sir?

Comment: No, you have `private void SearchCommandExecute() { var tempRecords = _customerList.Where(c => c.FullName.Contains(Text)); Customer = new List<Customer>(tempRecords); }`

Comment: look at this Sir. I have this code but I'm having error on the 'Text' and 'Customer' part. 
        private void SearchCommandExecute()
        {
            var tempRecords = _customerList.Where(c => c.CUSTOMER_NAME.Contains(Text));
            Customer = new List<Customer>(tempRecords);
        }
        public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an addition to the answer of Egor Gromadskiy, but as there are so many comments on other subjects I post it here.

Keep in mind that when in the search bar X button or cancel button is pressed, search command will not be triggered. So if you want to show all results on this event, call this command from the SearchText property (in this case, SearchText is set to null, at least on iOS, for Android refer to [this forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21293/xamarin-forms-searchbar-which-event-does-the-cancel-button-fire)).

The same can be done if you want an as-you-type search and don't wait till Search button is hit.

```
public string SearchText
{
  get { ... }
  set { 
        ... = value;
        SearchCommand.Execute();
      }
}
```